# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address') when i try deploying contracts in Hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat-deploy

so i'v 2 smart contracts token.sol

```
contract Token is IERC20, ReentrancyGuard {

    string private Name;
    string private Sympol;
    uint private Decimal;
    uint private TotalSupply;

    address public owner;
    mapping (address user  => uint balance ) BalanceOf;
    mapping (address tokenOwner  => mapping (address spender  => uint amount )) Allowed;
    mapping (address burner  => uint amount ) public burnedTokens;

    
    mapping (address burner  => uint  number) RewardCounter;


    Stake private stake;
    mapping(address => uint256 dateOfstackingEndsInUnixTimesStamp) public stakingPeriod;

    
    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _sympol, uint _decimal, uint _totalSupply, address _stake) {
        Name = _name;
        Sympol = _sympol;
        Decimal = _decimal;
        TotalSupply = _totalSupply;
        BalanceOf[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
        stake = Stake(_stake);
    }
        // the rest of the code ...
}
```

and i'v stake.sol

```
contract Stake {
    Token private token;
    mapping (address user => uint amount) stakeOf;
    
    constructor(address _token) {
        token = Token(_token);
    }
    //the rest of the code
```

this is how i deploy theme in token.js

```js
let Token, token, Stake, stake
    let accounts = []
    let owner, user1, user2, user3, user4, burner, staker
    

    beforeEach( async()=>{
        // setup accounts
        accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        owner = accounts[0]
        user1 = accounts[1]
        user2 = accounts[2]
        user3 = accounts[3]
        user4 = accounts[4]
        burner = accounts[5]
        staker = accounts[6]
        // load Contracts 
        Token = await ethers.getContractFactory('Token')
        Stake = await ethers.getContractFactory('Stake')
        // deploy Contract
        try {
            stake = await Stake.deploy( token.address)
            console.log(`stake address:    ${stake.address}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error deploying Stake contract:', error);
        }
        token = await Token.deploy(
            'YasCoin', 'YCN', 18, YasCoin(1000),stake.address
        )
        
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

i fix it was a circular dependency problem because in both of the constructor of the smart contracts they depeand on each other address before they even deployed, so i deploy both of theme without the addresses and i add 2 function they hold the address of the other contract after both are deployed like this

```
//token.sol
function setStakeContract(address _stake) public {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Only the owner can set the Stake contract");
        stake = Stake(_stake);
    }
//stake.sol
 function setTokenContract(address _token) public {
        token = Token(_token);
    }
//then i add this to my test file after deployment statments
            await token.setStakeContract(stake.target);
            await stake.setTokenContract(token.target);
```

Answer (score 0):

`stake.address` won't work, it's actually `stake.target`. Let me know if the error persists.

Comment: i appreciate your response , using your suggestion i did this 

```solidity

try {
            stake = await Stake.deploy( token.target(), YasCoin(1000))
            console.log(`stake address:    ${stake.address}`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error deploying Stake contract:', error);
        }
        token = await Token.deploy(
            'YasCoin', 'YCN', 18, YasCoin(1000),stake.target()
        )
```

now and i've got this error
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

Comment: After deploying the contract, add this line too. `stake = await stake.waitForDeployment`. This will make sure your contract is deployed before accessing the address. And if it still doesn't works, then try to console the `stake` instance itself to know whether or not the contract is deployed.

Comment: thank you @Zartaj Afser i solve it it was a circular dependency problem

Comment: Cool, happy coding.